# TSQL statement to iterate over XML nodes in field

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, iterator

I have 2 fields with random list of values like this where the lists are separated by spaces

```
field1,field2
2 4 8 4,A B C B
```

The values and the count in fields are random (A is not always in index 1 of field 2 so it can be

```
field1,field2
2 8,B A
```

Only thing that is consistent is the A B C.
What I need is to sum up the values and create columns
so far I have this

```
SELECT
CAST (N'<H><r>' + REPLACE([field1], ' ', '</r><r>')  + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals],
CAST (N'<H><r>' + REPLACE([field], ' ', '</r><r>')  + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [cols]
FROM tt
```

for some reason I can't use a variable like this

```
DECLARE @A
    Select 
    CASE WHEN 
    [cols].value('count(/H/r)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = 'A' THEN @A = @A + [vals].value('count(/H/r)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') END
    from .....
```

I'm lost I can't even assign values to variables and return data in TSQL 
I tried the WHILE loop within the SELECT statement without luck

Any help with this appretiated

Comment: Looking for this: `DECLARE @A INT = (SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END);`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need the while loop?

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    --Generate an identifier for each row (if none exists)
    row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
   ,vals   = CAST (N'<val>' + REPLACE([field1], ' ', '</val><val>')  + '</val>' AS XML)
   ,cols   = CAST (N'<col>' + REPLACE([field2], ' ', '</col><col>')  + '</col>' AS XML)
  FROM tt
)
SELECT
  row_id
 ,col_id   = col.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 ,value    = val.value('.','varchar(max)') 
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY vals.nodes('val') v(val)
OUTER APPLY cols.nodes('col') c(col)
WHERE 
  --Get the node position by counting the preceding siblings. Only return rows where val position equals col position.
  val.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') = col.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your code got me very close to what I needed, I'm still trying to understand the count(../*[. << $i]) part